# Trigger keyframes animations without js/jquery

Tags: css, keyframe

Is there a option to trigger keyframes animation without using js/jquery?
I thought about :hover, but it would be a bit complicated for my purpose.

Comment: What is your need in full? You say that you thought about `:hover` but would be complicated. Why do you think it would be complicated? When should the animation actually be triggered (on hover, on click, on load, when?)? Where is your code?

Comment: I want to attend a contest, so I am not allowed to use js/jquery. :hover would be complicated only in my purpose. It would be easy to use jquery and trigger animations on scroll, but when I can't do that, I have to find sth alternative.

Comment: I understand why you can't use JS/jQuery but your question is pretty vague and unclear of your actual needs. My understanding of your comment is that you want the animation to be triggered when user scrolls and if that is correct then CSS is not the right tool because you need to know when the user has scrolled.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. I have to find another way to do it or change my concept.

Comment: See my answer. Might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted something like this? This is the best I can do without JavaScript! Although I had fun doing it.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label{
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
  border:thin solid black;
  display:block;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
  content: "Run Baby!";

}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  content: "Come back!";
}
.run {
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: thin solid red;
  transition: all 5000ms ease;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 100px;
}
.run:before {
  content: "I wanna go right ->";
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + .run {
  left: 400px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + .run:before {
  content: "Hey! Look at me go!";
}
```

```html
<input id="nice" type="checkbox">
<label for="nice">
</label>

<div class="run"></div>
```